# Unable to open the specified URL on a real device while running Selenium tests using ios-driver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, mobile

I am trying to automate mobile web testing using [ios-driver](https://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/) on an iPhone 6 plus (real device). The Safari browser opens but the specified URL (google.com in this case) is not opened (i.e. only "about:blank page" is displayed).

The configuration as shown on a terminal by running the command `java -jar ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar -newSessionTimeoutSec 40 -port 4444 -beta` is:

```
Running on: Mac OS X 10.10 (x86_64)
Using java: 1.8.0_45
Using Xcode install: /Applications/Xcode.app
Using instruments: version:6.3.2, build: 57082
Using iOS version 8.3
```

The device I have connected is also recognized properly.

The Java code I used is as follows:

```
IOSCapabilities capabilities = IOSCapabilities.iphone("Safari");
capabilities.setCapability(IOSCapabilities.SIMULATOR, false);
capabilities.setCapability(IOSCapabilities.UUID, "UID-of-Device");
capabilities.setCapability("javascriptEnabled", true);
RemoteIOSDriver webDriver = null;
try {
    webDriver = new RemoteIOSDriver(new URL(     "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
} catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
webDriver.get("https://www.apple.com/");
webDriver.quit();
```

The following error is displayed:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: is Safari started and with the focus ?
```

Any help in solving this error would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with the driver. Looks like a bug with the code.

https://github.com/ios-driver/ios-driver/issues/369

Update 3/24/2017: The linked issue is still open. The driver appears to have continuing issues with this scenario.

Comment: Yes. I saw that thread and also commented there. Seems that driver is having some issue as till now I am not able to get any solution.